# Why TCP socket send a RST packet instead of resending data when receives an incorrect ACK?

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, sockets, tcp, tcpdump

One the 'cool' things about TPC connections is that data is not lost. When data is not ACKed, TCP *supposedly* resends the data.

I have a classic games server written in c++ and the client is written in Flash AS3.

In the client i've added a checker tool that tries to connect to YouTube and Twitter each X seconds with a timeout of 5 seconds. The problem is that after the internet connection of the client is broken during some seconds (Internet checker receives 1 or 2 timeouts, but after that receives OKs), it starts receiving data from the server but the server stops receiving data from the client.

This is the flow received by TCPDUMP:

```
1. server > client: Flags [P.], seq 2374:2378, ack 119, win 14600, length 4
2. client > server: Flags [.], ack 2374, win 15524, length 0
3. client > server: Flags [.], ack 2378, win 15520, length 0
 . [Here the client sends data to the server, but the server never receives it...]
4. server > client: Flags [P.], seq 2378:2383, ack 119, win 14600, length 5
5. server > client: Flags [P.], seq 2386:2389, ack 119, win 14600, length 3
6. client > server: Flags [.], ack 2386, win 15512, length 0
7. client > server: Flags [.], ack 2389, win 15509, length 0
8. client > server: Flags [R.], seq 127, ack 2389, win 0, length 0
```

As you can read, when the server send data with an incorrect ACK, the client istead of resending the data, sends a RST packet (forcing the server to close the connection). In the client log I can see that receives and process the data sent by the server (So the connection is not closed when the server sends an incorrect ACK).

When TCP decides to send a RST packet instead of resending data after receiving an incorrect ACK?

The client socket is an AS3 `Socket` defined this way:

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket();
```

And the server socket is set non-blocking with `fcntl()`. Also has this options:

```
setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&dummyint, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&dummyint, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: There's no 'supposedly' about it. It does resend the data. Which do you think is more likely: a bug in a protocol with over 30 years' development behind it, and a world wide deployment on the Internet, that is demonstrably stable on a very large number of platforms, with millions upon millions of users, or a bug in your brand new unseen code? I suggest you post it here for comment rather then just speculate, if you want a solution. However from the nature of post it doesn't appear that you are even asking a real question.

Comment: I'm not telling a protocol with over 30 years has a bug... I'm not that kind of person :-/ I'm telling that seems that there are times that TCP decides to send a RST packet instead of resending data and I don't know why. I need to know why happens this so I can workaround it. Going to edit the post so it's more clear.

Comment: That is *exactly* what you said. You used the word 'supposedly', and your post also contained the text "what's wrong with TCP?", At least until you edited it. If you have a real question, ask it, and include the code concerned, or rather a short enough extract that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I see. Sorry but my english is not good enough. When I wrote it it don't sound as bad as you told me, that's because I edited it. And I still think about 'supposedly' because tcpdump shows that don't resends the data. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What value is in "dummyint" when you're doing those `setsockopt()` calls?

Comment: Does your (still unseen) code also modify the SO_LINGER option?

Comment: No, the only things my code modify is what you see. The code is about 9k lines and the rest of lines are `send`, `recv` and client/server processing data, i'm not going to paste 9k lines. Before c++ I had the server programmed in ruby and had the same problem too. The problem is with TCP so code has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there seems to be an additional packet missing from the dump, server bytes 2383-2385, though it seems the client did see them because it ACK'd them.

The server isn't replying with an incorrect ACK.  It's replying with an ACK of the last byte-number it saw in the stream, #119.  It's up to the client to retransmit those missing bytes when the server fails to ACK them after some period of time.  Instead, it's sending a RST.

There's no timing information but I'd have to guess that the RST is coming from a time-out on the client before the information was due to be re-transmitted.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I've followed a bit more packets and server bytes are strange, before all this happens it sends `bytes 2261:2324` and receives both ACKs and a third ACK `2328` so seems that there was more problems sending/receiving data. I've checked timings and yes, the RST packet is received 3 seconds after the server sent last info so it's possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

TCP is not "unstable" per se, it's a protocol.  If anything is unstable it's your network connection.  TCP has an algorithm for retrying on unstable networks.  It's also possible there's something wrong with your code, and it's possible there's an intermediary device timing out your connection.

Comment: Yes, I know that TCP is only a protocol. With unstable I was talking about the socket created, hence, the connection. I don't think that a 3rd party terminates the connection because the RST packet is received when the client receives an incorrect ACK after sending data that the server don't receives.